# Javascript to add line breaks between inline elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to insert line breaks into dynamically generated html (so that text which appears within inline-block elements is placed bottom left of images). What I have doesn't cut it. A pattern search is required to find where end divs with inline-attachment class are NOT followed by an end div with inline-attachment class. As the text and inline-attachment elements are dynamically generated, the number which appear consecutively is arbitrary. I'm stumped.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  contentBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
  for (i = 0, len = contentBlocks.length; i < len; i++) {
    firstInline = contentBlocks[i].querySelector('.inline-attachment');
    firstInline.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br />');

    lastInline = contentBlocks[i].querySelector('.inline-attachment:last-of-type');
    lastInline.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br />');
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.inline-attachment {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  text top left
  <div class="inline-attachment">
    <dl class="thumbnail">
      <dt><a href=""><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2duxRXndQoYlHxjCw2U6rQTOJPYvFqx6AzA&usqp=CAU" /></a></dt>
      <dd></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-attachment">
    <dl class="thumbnail">
      <dt><a href=""><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2duxRXndQoYlHxjCw2U6rQTOJPYvFqx6AzA&usqp=CAU" /></a></dt>
      <dd></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  text should be bottom left
  <div class="inline-attachment">
    <dl class="thumbnail">
      <dt><a href=""><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2duxRXndQoYlHxjCw2U6rQTOJPYvFqx6AzA&usqp=CAU" /></a></dt>
      <dd></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  text bottom left
</div>
```

Comment: You say "text which appears within inline-block elements", but the text is outside of those elements.

Comment: You have a point there. I'm unsure therefore why it inherits the inline-block style. Applying display:block to the containing div doesn't help. Inserting line breaks before the text does.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to solve the problem this way? (using a pattern search?). Wouldn't it be possible to generate three divs, each containing an image and the text below it? Then you can place the three divs next to each other.

Comment: The html is generated by phpBB (forum). The default style for the images is not inline, however, on a desktop they use the screen space more elegantly when styled inline.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cv68jzqa/) what you need?

Comment: @AgentX the text doesn't "inherit" any style, but because text is not an element. And as it stands, the text is in no way grouped with the attachment, so I'm not sure what you want is even doable without HTML changes.

Comment: Teemu - thanks, but unfortunately the consecutive inline images are no longer side by side.

Comment: Siguza - the HTML structure is determined by core pbpBB files. It should be doable because manually injecting <br /> tags solves the layout. The challenge is to insert them using JS in accordance with the pattern described: "where end divs with inline-attachment class are NOT followed by an end div with inline-attachment class."